# how can i grab [...] section in a written text

Tags: javascript, php

i want to make a question box just like how SO has one.but i dont know how SO grab some special text in the page.

if i want to add a link to my question i must type like `[writing to appear][URL]`. How SO translate this. i mean how it understand its a link.Is there a source for this?

Another question SO do this in the same page too.When i type it it shows the prewiev at blow page.  Is this a javascript code then?

**NOTE** *Wikipedia has same property while you editing it. i just wanted to say.*

Comment: ..what's SoF? more info please

Comment: @Farkie [SoF](http://stackoverflow.com) i thought everyone here knows this.

Comment: @Farkie do you answer now?

Comment: Have a go :P We aren't here to service you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions in PHP.

If you want to replace the `[writing][URL]` with an actual HTML link you can use `preg_replace` like this:

```
preg_replace("/\[(.*?)\]\[(.*?)\]/", "<a href='$2'>$1</a>", $text);
```

Otherwise if you just want to match the `[writing][URL]` you can use `preg_match` like this:

```
preg_match("/\[(.*?)\]\[(.*?)\]/", $text);
```

Comment: thanks for that. but can i ask why we use / at beginnig and end

Comment: @user3301042 / at the beginning and end means that we are creating a regular expression and not just a regular string

Comment: @user3301042 See [this](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php) for some RegExp (or Regular Expression) examples.